# How to configure mod_lua (apache) to use LuaJIT?

Tags: apache, lua, webserver, luajit

How do I configure **[mod_lua](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_lua.html)** to use [**LuaJIT**](http://luajit.org/), instead of just plain **[Lua](http://lua.org)**?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to compile Apache 2.3 and link mod_lua against LuaJIT 2.0b6 like this:

```
LUA_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -lluajit-51 -lm" \
LUA_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/luajit-2.0" \
./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
    --enable-lua --with-lua=/dev/null --enable-luajit
make
```

As far as I can tell, even though there's an `--enable-luajit` configuration flag, the mod_lua config.m4 script only looks for lua libraries by default.

If you built LuaJIT as a dynamic library as well as a static library, you may want to explicitly link it statically:

```
LUA_LIBS="/usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.a -lm"
```

(You may have to change the paths depending on which version of LuaJIT you have installed, and where.  Caveat lector: I didn't actually install and test the results of this.)

Comment: Any idea how I'd deploy Super-NGINX on Debian? It's a script that has LuaJIT/NGINX already built -->  https://github.com/ezmobius/super-nginx